# Using session cookie with same site strict without breaking OAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cookies, oauth, omniauth

I have a Rails app that has two broad flows, one is the Admin login and another is the Customer Web. I want to make the session cookie use the `same_site: strict` option as the application has sensitive data and involves money transactions.

[image]
Enabling `same_site: strict` breaks the Omniauth Google OAuth flow for logging into Admin and throws a CSRF error (because the session cookie is not being passed in the redirect).

Is there any way to make the OAuth work with `same_site: strict` option?
Or, is there any way in Rails to have two different session cookies one with `strict` and another with `lax` option and use them both in the individual flows?

I didn't find much around this, most posts just ask to use `lax` option. I tried using multiple session stores but Rails only ends up using one session for the entire application.

Comment: _"Is there any way to make the OAuth work with same_site: strict option?"_ - the CSRF check _needs_ a working session, so unless you wanted to disable that to begin with (depends on the OAuth provider, if they let you do that in the first place), then - no.

Comment: And even if you used to "separate" sessions, somehow - you would still need to pick up your original session at some point ... Otherwise, where would you want to store the essential parts of the OAuth _result_ (i.e., at least the access token)?